# how i can resolve the error postman 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, postman

I am developing the backend part for the registration of a user in my site.

the problem i have is when i want to test if my code works in postman i get the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-29T13:38:13.114+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/adduser"
}
```

I really don't know where this error can come from, here is the configuration code I put for spring security:

```
package com.app.habilitation.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").
        fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("hr")
        .password("{noop}hr").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

and this is my controller :

```
package com.app.habilitation.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;
import com.app.habilitation.service.UserService;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController (UserService theuserService) {
        userService=theuserService;
    }


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String login() {
        return "authenticaated succesfully";
    }

    @GetMapping("/getUsers") 
    public String getUsers() {
        return "users";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public UserEntity addUser (@RequestBody UserEntity theUser) {

        userService.save(theUser);

        return theUser;
    }
}
```

I added the cross origin to try to resolve my error but it does not work :( here is what I did as you could see in my controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

this is my dao using jpa :

```
package com.app.habilitation.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;

public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {



}
```

and this is my entity class :

```
package com.app.habilitation.entity;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ORDO_DEP_UTILISATEUR")
public class UserEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="IDENTIFIANT")
    private Integer IDENTIFIANT;

    /*@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOI") */
    @Column(name="EMPLOI")
    private Integer emploi;

    /* @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="ENTITE") */
    @Column(name="ENTITE")
    private Integer entite;


    @Column(name="LOGIN")
    private String login;


    @Column(name="MOTDEPASSE")
    private String mdp;


    @Column(name="nom")
    private String nom;

    @Column(name="prenom")
    private String prenom;

    @Column(name="CREERPAR")
    private Integer creerpar;

    @Column(name="ANNULEPAR")
    private Integer annulepar;

    @Column(name="STATUT")
    private String statut;

    @Column(name="DATEEFFET")
    private Date dateeffet;


    @Column(name="DATEFIN")
    private Date datefin;

    @Column(name="CREELE")
    private Date creele;

    @Column(name="MOTIFDEDESACTIVATION")
    private String motifdedesactivation;

    @Column(name="ANNULELE")
    private Date annulele;

    public Integer getIDENTIFIANT() {
        return IDENTIFIANT;
    }

    public void setIDENTIFIANT(Integer iDENTIFIANT) {
        IDENTIFIANT = iDENTIFIANT;
    }

    public Integer getEmploi() {
        return emploi;
    }

    public void setEmploi(Integer emploi) {
        this.emploi = emploi;
    }

    public Integer getEntite() {
        return entite;
    }

    public void setEntite(Integer entite) {
        this.entite = entite;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getMdp() {
        return mdp;
    }

    public void setMdp(String mdp) {
        this.mdp = mdp;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public Integer getCreerpar() {
        return creerpar;
    }

    public void setCreerpar(Integer creerpar) {
        this.creerpar = creerpar;
    }

    public Integer getAnnulepar() {
        return annulepar;
    }

    public void setAnnulepar(Integer annulepar) {
        this.annulepar = annulepar;
    }

    public String getStatut() {
        return statut;
    }

    public void setStatut(String statut) {
        this.statut = statut;
    }

    public Date getDateeffet() {
        return dateeffet;
    }

    public void setDateeffet(Date dateeffet) {
        this.dateeffet = dateeffet;
    }

    public Date getDatefin() {
        return datefin;
    }

    public void setDatefin(Date datefin) {
        this.datefin = datefin;
    }

    public Date getCreele() {
        return creele;
    }

    public void setCreele(Date creele) {
        this.creele = creele;
    }

    public String getMotifdedesactivation() {
        return motifdedesactivation;
    }

    public void setMotifdedesactivation(String motifdedesactivation) {
        this.motifdedesactivation = motifdedesactivation;
    }

    public Date getAnnulele() {
        return annulele;
    }

    public void setAnnulele(Date annulele) {
        this.annulele = annulele;
    }

    public UserEntity(Integer iDENTIFIANT, Integer emploi, Integer entite, String login, String mdp, String nom,
            String prenom, Integer creerpar, Integer annulepar, String statut, Date dateeffet, Date datefin,
            Date creele, String motifdedesactivation, Date annulele) {
        IDENTIFIANT = iDENTIFIANT;
        this.emploi = emploi;
        this.entite = entite;
        this.login = login;
        this.mdp = mdp;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.creerpar = creerpar;
        this.annulepar = annulepar;
        this.statut = statut;
        this.dateeffet = dateeffet;
        this.datefin = datefin;
        this.creele = creele;
        this.motifdedesactivation = motifdedesactivation;
        this.annulele = annulele;
    }

    public UserEntity() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserEntity [IDENTIFIANT=" + IDENTIFIANT + ", emploi=" + emploi + ", entite=" + entite + ", login="
                + login + ", mdp=" + mdp + ", nom=" + nom + ", prenom=" + prenom + ", creerpar=" + creerpar
                + ", annulepar=" + annulepar + ", statut=" + statut + ", dateeffet=" + dateeffet + ", datefin="
                + datefin + ", creele=" + creele + ", motifdedesactivation=" + motifdedesactivation + ", annulele="
                + annulele + "]";
    }



}
```

this is my userService interface :

```
package com.app.habilitation.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;



public interface UserService {




    public void save (UserEntity theUser);


}
```

and this is my userServiceImpl :

```
package com.app.habilitation.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.app.habilitation.dao.UserDao;
import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired

    public UserServiceImpl (UserDao theuserDao) {

        userDao = theuserDao;
    }



    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(UserEntity theUser) {

        userDao.save(theUser);

    }



}
```

and this is my application.properties ( i change port 8080 to 8484 because a nother application use port 8080 and for info i use oracle 10g) :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
spring.datasource.username=nawfel       
spring.datasource.password=hr


server.port=8484
```

can someone help me please ? :(

Comment: Try putting @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") on top of each @getmapping?

Comment: @postmapping and also keep it there as well where you have it currently.

Comment: no it doesn't work :(

Comment: instead of * try putting http://locahost:4200 in all annotations.

Comment: it doesn't work yet :(

Comment: are you passing authorization header from postman?

Comment: can you explain to me please because I'm still a beginner this is my first application in angular spring boot, security and postman

Comment: https://harperdbhelp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010250207-Basic-Auth-with-Postman

Comment: did it help? can you tell?

Comment: I followed the tutorial that you sent me but in step 5 to save the username and password I don't see any button that allows you to do this in my post man

Comment: I made a screen but I don't know how to show it to you here in the comments

Comment: just send your request after putting your username and password. no need to save it. and restore your crossorigin to * in each annotation.

Comment: it doesn't work it always gives me status 401 Unauthorized :(

Comment: what is the username and password you put?

Comment: username : hr password : hr but he give me i new error now, this is the new error : "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)\r\n\tat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing The AuthenticationManagerBuilder code as given below :-

```
 @Override
    protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("hr")
        .password("hr").roles("USER");
    }
```

And set user name password from postman same. username hr and password hr.

If you don't know how to do so follow this link :- https://harperdbhelp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010250207-Basic-Auth-with-Postman

Comment: i have a new error :  "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)\r\n\tat

Comment: put this code back and try sending username password mentioned in this code from your postman. and check in request headers in post man whether the username and password you enter is going.

Comment: i put username = hr and password = hr in postman but i have already the same error "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement\r\n\tat

Comment: you put this code back uncommented? and in the code your password doesn't seem hr

Comment: yes I removed the comments, and if my password is correct hr (in my code there is the {noop} but it is just an annontiation of spring security to make the password encrypted or not)

Comment: try removing {noop} from password?

Comment: https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/spring-security-in-memory-authentication

Comment: I deleted {noop} as you told me but the same error still remains :(

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: its while restarting server or while hitting api?

Comment: I restarted the server and closed postman and I re-opened it and re-started the server but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: if its while hitting api try putting a System.out.println in your api in first line and see if its printing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214917/discussion-between-aakash-garg-and-nawfal-bougrine).